# How to apply Many2many field filter in search view for odoo 10

Tags: filter, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-10

[image]i have a many2many field and i want to apply domain in search view. But i'm getting following error while filtering "Uncaught Error: Failed to evaluate search criterions: ".
**My xml code is here:**

```
<record id="view_partner_fare_well_ser_search_master" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Farewell Room Search</field>
        <field name="model">fare.well.room.ser</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Farewell Room">
                <group string="Order By">
                    <filter string="Farewell Room" context="{'group_by':'room'}" help="Farewell Room"/>
                </group>
                <field name="single_room_show"/>
                <filter string="Farewell Room" domain="[('id','in',single_room_show and single_room_show[0] and
                single_room_show[0][2] or False)]"
                        name="my_farewell_room_filter"/>
            </search>
        </field>
    </record>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? What is the many2many field? What can be in it and what do you want to search?

Comment: i have two types tree views with different actions. Add i want that in one view all records visible and another view selected records visible according to condition. For this, i gathered selected records in many2many field('single_room_show'). But when i applied domain in search view according to this many2many then above error shows. So, please give me appropriate solution for this problem.